# TestNG reporter not logging for exceptions

Tags: java, logging, selenium, testng

Hey guys I am trying to customize the output of my selenium framework using testNG.  Right now I have an 'action' class which is wrapping all the selenium methods and I am wraping those up in try catches.  Here's an example. (I am manually throwing the exception for testing purposes.)

```
public void closeBrowser(){
    try{
        driver.quit();
        throw new WebDriverException();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        ExceptionHandler exception = new ExceptionHandler(e, null);
    }
}
```

My exception handler class looks like this:

```
public ExceptionHandler(Exception exceptionName, String element){
        this.exceptionName = exceptionName;
        this.element = element;
        report();
}

public void report(){

    String delims = "[.]";
    String[] tokens = exceptionName.getClass().toString().split(delims);
    System.out.println(tokens[tokens.length-1]);

    switch(tokens[tokens.length-1]){
        case "WebDriverException":
            System.out.println("Made it to case 1");
            Reporter.log("Test Message here <------ \n", true);
            break;
        default:
            Reporter.log("Unknown Exception");


    }

}
```

When I run  I get this output on the console:

```
WebDriverException
Made it to case 1
Test Message here <------
```

But I never get anything in the HTML files that TestNG generates.   Any ideas??

Comment: How do you run TestNG? It may have to do with if you run it via command line or programatically. I run TestNG inside a wrapper class with testng.run() and I get the output to both System.out and the HTML reports.

Comment: I am running via XML within eclipse.  The HTML file is changing with every run but the log it never changed.

Comment: Ah ok. I run mine with the command line, so I'm not sure how eclipse runs it differently